# Simple cartesian plane with straight lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

How to generate the above plot with pgfplots?

I have an example code here:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis equal,grid=both]
\addplot coordinates{(-3,1) (6,-2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which will generate a figure as shown below:

[image]

I don't want grid lines to be drawn full.

Only small xticks and yticks are needed.

Don't want dots to be placed at the ends of line.

Comment: Unrelated: You should always set the compat level when using PGFPlots - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily done with `pstricks`:

```
    \documentclass[svgnames, pstricks, border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-plot, pst-node}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-1.5)(6,6.5)
    \psset{showorigin=false, arrowinset=0.12, linejoin=1, labelsep=1pt}
    \everypsbox{\scriptsize}
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle, tickstyle=full, ticksize=2pt -2pt, Dx=1, labels=none, linecolor=LightSteelBlue]{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-1.5)(5.5, 6)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pnodes(-0.5,-1.5){A} (5,4){B}(-0.5,3.5){C}(4,-1){D}
    \ncline[linecolor=Tomato]{A}{B}\naput[nrot=:U, npos=0.8]{$ x-y=1 $}
    \ncline[linecolor=LawnGreen]{C}{D}\naput[nrot=:U, npos=0.3]{$ x+y=3 $}
    \dotnode(2,1){I}\uput{4pt}[r](I){$P(2,1)$}
    \end{pspicture*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See if the following is what you after:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    lbl/.style = {text=black, anchor=south, sloped},
    dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.6pt,
                  node contents={}}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    xlabel=$x$, x label style={anchor=west}, 
    ylabel=$y$, y label style={anchor=south}, 
    grid=both,
    ytick={-5,-4,...,9},
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, fill=white,
                     inner sep=2pt},
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=4.5,
    no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={green, thick}    
             ]
\addplot coordinates{(-1, 4) (5,-2)} 
            node[near start, lbl] {$x+y=3$};
\addplot coordinates{(-1,-2) (5, 4)}
            node[near end, lbl] {$x-y=1$};
\node at (2,1) [dot,label=right:${P(2,1)}$];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit (1):**
Diagram lines are in green color and thick.

**Edit (2):**
Intersection of lines is at $P(2,1)$ and not at $P(2.1)$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With Asymptote:

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
import graph;
real f(real x){return 3-x;}
real g(real x){return x-1;}
path pf=graph(f,-1,4.5);
path pg=graph(g,-1,5);
pair P=intersectionpoint(pf,pg);
draw((P.x,0)--P^^(0,P.y)--P,gray+dashed);
draw(Label("$x+y=3$",align=S,EndPoint),pf,blue+1pt);
draw(Label("$x-y=1$",align=N,EndPoint),pg,orange+1pt);
dot("$P=(1,2)$",align=2E,P,red);
label("O",align=SW,(0,0));
xaxis(Label("$x$",align=N),Ticks(begin=false,beginlabel=false,Step=1,step=0,Size=3,OmitTick(0)),Arrow(TeXHead));
yaxis(Label("$y$",align=E),Ticks(begin=false,beginlabel=false,Step=1,step=0,Size=3,OmitTick(0)),Arrow(TeXHead));

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot), based on TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzaxes(-1,-1)(6,6){$x$}{$y$}
\tzticks*(-2pt:2pt){1,2,...,5}(-2pt:2pt){1,2,...,5}
\tzfn"AA"{\x-1}[-1:5]{$x-y=1$}[a]
\tzfn"BB"{-\x+3}[-1:4]
\tznode(0,3){$x+y=3$}[r]
\tzXpoint*{AA}{BB}{$P(2,1)$}[0]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
axis equal,
xticklabels=none, yticklabels=none,
]
\addplot[green, no marks] coordinates{(-3,1) (6,-2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Linear graph]

Comment: Can you generate the first figure in the question fully.

Comment: how to annotate \addplot[green, no marks] coordinates{(-3,1) (6,-2)}; with straight line equation x = -3y.